# How to return count of items found in SQL query

Tags: php, wp-query, wpdb

I have a table of hikers and hike sign up data, and need to query it to find out if a particular hiker has already signed up or not.  Each signup has a unique key that I can query against.     I've tried numerous things, read numerous FAQS and still no luck.  I must be missing something simple I guess.

Running the function does not result in an error, it just doesn't return anything.   I all the function as a shortcode, and ideally it would echo the result on my test page.   But, nada.

My database table name is:  'Hike_Sign_Up_Form'
The field name to search against:  'hike_hiker_key'
Hardcoded (temporarily) search for:  'SCAMR WordPressAdminSan Tan - Goldmine Loop - 2 Nov 2016 - Casual Intermediate'

Here is my code:

```
function ck_if_already_signed_up(){
   global $wpdb;    
    $tempresults=$wpdb->get_results(("SELECT count(*) FROM $wpdb->wp_cf7dbplugin_submits WHERE form_name ='Hike_Sign_Up_Form' AND field_name = 'hike_hiker_key' AND field_value = 'SCAMR WordPressAdminSan Tan - Goldmine Loop - 2 Nov 2016 - Casual Intermediate'"),ARRAY_N);
    $results=$tempresults->num_rows;
    return $results;

}
```

I have also tried this:

```
function ck_if_already_signed_up(){
   global $wpdb;    
    $results=$wpdb->get_var(("SELECT count(*) FROM $wpdb->wp_cf7dbplugin_submits WHERE form_name ='Hike_Sign_Up_Form' AND field_name = 'hike_hiker_key' AND field_value = 'SCAMR WordPressAdminSan Tan - Goldmine Loop - 2 Nov 2016 - Casual Intermediate'"),ARRAY_N);
       return $results;

}
```

But no joy there either.  Any pointers for this new-bee would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try running the queries against mysql directly (via phpmyadmin, heidiSQL or the command line client for example) to see if they work (and work as expected)?

Comment: Hi.  Yes, I did, and it works like a charm that way (via phpmyadmin).

Comment: What about `var_export($results);`? Are you sure the function actually gets called?

Comment: ah!  That returned NULL.   hmm..

Comment: I'm not sure if the double parentheses (`$wpdb->get_var((`) you have lead to problems, try removing one pair.

Comment: Removed the double parenthesis - no change.  I tried the following as well, no difference.  var_export($results) still returns NULL.

`$second_db=new wpdb(DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME,DB_HOST);
    $results=$second_db->get_var(("SELECT count(*) FROM $second_db->wp_cf7dbplugin_submits WHERE form_name = 'Hike_Sign_Up_Form' AND field_name = 'hike_hiker_key' AND field_value = 
'Dave IreyQueen Creek Old Hwy 60 (S) - 11 Jan 2017'"),ARRAY_N);
    var_export($results);`

Comment: sorry about the format above, I tried reformatting but system won't let me edit it further....

Comment: No worries, it's readable. Please add `$wpdb->show_errors();` (or $second_db->show_errors()) before the ->get_var(). Also look at $wpdb->last_query to make sure that `->wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` is correctly expanded.

Comment: Janh2 - THANK YOU so much for your help!  Your pointers, and being able to see the debug/output made all the difference.    It is working now.  Here's the code:  `$querystring="Richard SwallowParker Pass (CI) – 9Nov2016";

$query = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT count(*) FROM `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` WHERE `form_name` = %s AND `field_name` = %s AND `field_value` = %s", 'Hike_Sign_Up_Form','hike_hiker_key',$querystring); $results=$wpdb->get_var($query);return($results);`